# Qual è il significato di "strafarsi" in questa frase?

Tags: verbs, meaning

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto:

> Sei un poveraccio figlio di un suicida e con uno zio alcolizzato, lavori nel letamaio e **ti strafai** di stramonio e funghi allucinogeni, altro che gnomi.

Ho trovato il significato di "strafare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non quello di "strafarsi". Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi qual è il senso dell'espressione "ti strafai" nel passaggio precedente?

Comment: Per curiosità lessicografica: è vero che molti dizionari non registrano “strafarsi” in questo senso (ma il Devoto-Oli sì, con la marca “gerg[ale]” e la definizione “Drogarsi pesantemente”), ma quasi tutti registrano l'aggettivo “strafatto”.

Comment: Corretto. Dall'aggettivo passi poi al partecipio passato e al verbo ;)

Comment: Grazie: se non fosse stato corretto avrei fatto a meno di scriverlo. ;)

Comment: @DaG mica volevo avanzare dubbi ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Fatto" si usa come sinonimo di "drogato", "sotto effetto di stupefacenti"; "strafatto" si utilizza come accrescitivo per calcare il concetto.

"Strafarsi" significa quindi essere drogati in maniera esagerata.